# Is page navigation in JSP with javascript against standards?

Tags: navigation

I have a multi-language website (JSP) which asks users to choose language in the very first page. I finalized a reveal modal with hyperlinks showing each language in its original script. I need to submit the language choice in JSP and store in the session parameter.

If I do this with hyperlinks and javascript call, is there anything bad in it? Should I use separate forms and buttons instead for each language? are there other better methods which conform to internet standards and SEO ?

Comment: Out of intrest why would you want to bother your site visitors with an unnesscary step? since you can detect countries using GEO IP and combined with [NavigatorLanguage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages) you can safely select the correct language.

Comment: This is the context http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers_in_India -  Mine is a website designed to reach out to more non-english speaking people. I don't think many are supported at browser/os locale level to detect automatically.